# Angular. It won't route to desired page, I dont know how to fix it

Tags: angular, routes, hyperlink

I created a component called detail associated to a button but it won't route me to it, no error is displayed, I don't know how to solve it, thanks.

detail.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent {

  constructor( private router: Router){console.log('ciao')}
}
```

and this is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';
import { DisplayBookComponent } from './display-book/display-book.component';
import { AddBookComponent } from './add-book/add-book.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddBookComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'display',
    component: DisplayBookComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'display'
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the button is on the display-book.component, this is the ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BookServiceService } from "../book-service.service";
import { Book } from '../book';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: "app-display-book",
  templateUrl: "./display-book.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./display-book.component.scss"]
})
export class DisplayBookComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[] = [];

  constructor(private bookService: BookServiceService, public router:Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
      this.books = data;
    });
  }

  removeBook(book: Book) {
    this.bookService.removeBook(book.id.toString()).subscribe(() => {
      this.books = this.books.filter(b => b !== book);
    });
  }

  navigateToDetail(book: Book) {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', book.id]);
  }
  
  
}
```

and this is the html button in the display-book.html:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="navigateToDetail(book)">Detail</button>
```

and this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BookServiceService } from "./book-service.service";
import { DisplayBookComponent } from "./display-book/display-book.component";
import { AddBookComponent } from "./add-book/add-book.component";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { DetailComponent } from "./detail/detail.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: "add",
        component: AddBookComponent
      },
      {
        path: "display",
        component: DisplayBookComponent
      },
      {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: 'display'
      },
      {
        path: "detail",
        component: DetailComponent
      },
    ]),
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DisplayBookComponent,
    AddBookComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [BookServiceService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried to modify both the app-routing.module, the app.module.ts and add imports on the specs, import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";

Comment: change your RouterModule.forRoot(...) with AppRoutingModule

Comment: Have you tried to remove the / before detail inside of navigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your route config. Actually angular matches routes in a sequence as mentioned in routes array. So your '**' route should be at end. correct route config would be :-

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddBookComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'display',
    component: DisplayBookComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'display'
  }
];
```